Compact embeddings of Sobolev spaces on weighted infinite volume manifolds
I have seen it mentioned in several papers without proof or reference that the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(0,1)$ with exponential weight $p(x)=e^{|x|^2/4}$ has discrete spectrum for the weighted Laplace operator $\Delta_pu=\frac{1}{p(x)}\text{div}(p(x)\nabla u)$. I believe that the simplest way to prove this is to show that the embedding of weighted Sobolev spaces $H^1(M,p(x)dx)\rightarrow L^2(M,p(x)dx)$ is a compact operator. How does one go about showing this?
